# Finding Splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I need to find the splitting field of $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ over $Q$.

I managed to factorise it as $(x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 - x + 1)$ and so, the roots can easily be obtained from this factorisation. How do I determine the splitting field from the solution to the quadratic equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting field is, by definition or a brief argument, the field generated by the roots of the polynomial(s).

Thus when $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ are your roots (possibly some of them equal), then the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}[a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4]$.

You, then can simplify the description, for example by removing rational summands, or multiplying by rational constants.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The roots of the quadratics are all in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Comment: I got the solutions as $\frac{-1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Almost. In each case the second term is $\pm \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was looking for the explanation that the other answer provided! :)

Comment: You are welcome. After observing that the polynomial splits completely over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ you need to show no "cheaper" field will do. That is easy, for the polynomial does not split completely over the rationals, and our field has degree $2$ over the rationals, so there is no intermediate field.